# Negative number unexpectedly becoming positive

Tags: sql, sql-server

Negative numbers in my **num** column are unexpectedly displayed as positive. There's no explicit conversion in my code causing this. Any ideas on why?.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT;
SET @COUNT = 1;
DECLARE @ID_COUNT INT = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Logs);
DECLARE @TEMP INT;
SET @TEMP = 0;
DECLARE @EXIT BIT;
SET @EXIT = 0;

WHILE @COUNT < @ID_COUNT AND @EXIT = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CURRENT INT = (SELECT num FROM Logs WHERE id = @COUNT);
    IF @COUNT >= 2
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PREV INT = (SELECT num FROM Logs WHERE id = (@COUNT-1));

        IF @CURRENT = @PREV
        BEGIN
            SET @TEMP = @TEMP + 1;
        END;
    END;

    IF @TEMP = 2
    BEGIN
        SET @TEMP = @CURRENT;
        SET @EXIT = 1;
    END;

    IF @EXIT = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1;
    END;
END;

IF @TEMP <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @TEMP AS ConsecutiveNums;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 0 @TEMP AS ConsecutiveNums;
END;
```

---

This is the input:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 |
| 2 | -1 |
| 3 | -1 |

My Output:

| ConsecutiveNums |
| --- |
| 1 |

This is my expected output:

| ConsecutiveNums |
| --- |
| -1 |

Comment: Why are you using a loop. If you tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish we can probably assist you in creating set-based SQL (which is what you should be aiming for).

Comment: Yep, I try to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively.

Comment: When picking arbitrary numbers for testing, avoid numbers like 0, -1, and 1. It's too easy to produce them accidentally. Pick larger primes. 37, 23, 19.

Comment: You need to show a larger sample data set, I know we want a minimal example, but you need to show data that contains a few edge cases, some values that don't have 3 consecutive values etc.

Comment: The duplicate I have flagged shows you the easy and correct way to do this.

Comment: https://dev.to/ranggakd/consecutive-numbers-leetcode-mssql-5cb9#:~:text=Approach%201%3A%20Using%20LEAD%2C%20LAG,that%20appear%20consecutively%20three%20times.

Comment: @PowerMouse you don't want to use lead/lag unless you have to. The row_number approach is simple.

Comment: @DaleK, totally agree, overcomplicating